# SSL issue NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID on Chrome for computers running Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, windows-7, ssl-certificate

I have a few websites, and everything was running perfectly for the past months, but all of a sudden, they don't work anymore on Chrome for computers with Windows 7.

It works fine on Mozilla for these computers, and on all browsers with Windows version higher than 7.

Up at this point I've tried different solutions found online in articles like this:
https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/net-err_cert_date_invalid/

But nothing seems to work. On these computers, there are websites (other than mine) that have the same issue. The only common thing between these computers is the Windows version and the browser used.

If it helps, here is one of the websites https://suplimentenaturiste.ro/

I am thinking there must be an issue with the SSL itself, that was generated using Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe here can help you.
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/128686072/net-err-cert-date-invalid-error

From this answer :

> If you're on Win7 SP1 x64, try installing this update ("Support for urgent Trusted Root updates for Windows Root Certificate Program in Windows") - this worked for me:
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45633

I have the same problem, but this answer can fix it my problem!

Comment: It still does not solve the problem, giving the message "The update is not applicable to your computer". But thanks, it's definitely a way to move forward with investigating the issue.

Comment: Oh! Sorry can't help you. From official document: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/
,"Update September 30, 2021 As planned, the DST Root CA X3 cross-sign has expired,",So you should do something for update OS or certificate.
Maybe try this site method,"the 3 certificates above." !
https://www.stephenwagner.com/2021/09/30/sophos-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-problems-fix/
but I not try it,so I don't no what happen for download. It's seem a answer can fix it!

Comment: Since question is off topic I cannot post a new answer, so I will post it as a comment without a step-by-step. 
On Windows 7 you need to add three certificates for Let's Encrypt. Follow the steps suggested in comment #64 of this blog article: https://www.stephenwagner.com/2021/09/30/sophos-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-problems-fix/#comment-483119

Comment: It was very helpful. I saw a lot of problems around the certificate validity in windows 7 only in chrome browser.